# How to use GroupBy when we do it for the collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
private IDictionary<Guid, JobStatistic> GetAgentsStatistics(IList<Guid> agentIds, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        ...
        IDictionary<Guid, JobStatistic> jobStatistics = reportData.GroupBy(item => item.AgentId)
                                      .ToDictionary(items => items.Key, items => items.ToJobsStatistic());

        // Some agents might not have any records in specified period of time
        var missingAgents = agentIds.Except(jobStatistics.Keys);
        missingAgents.ForEach(agentId => jobStatistics.Add(agentId, new JobStatistic()));

        return jobStatistics;
    }
```

But now I change my DataContract (report data) and I need to use `item.AgentIds` instead of `item.AgentId`. How to change the code to do the same thing but with a collection of elements?

Comment: not getting you in tterms of AgentIds instead of AgentId

Comment: agentIds collection of  multiple agentId right ?,  but there is one properties of AgentId in reportData list....you can not group by on different values of same properties...you can groupby on properites....if i didn't understand then please elabarote the question

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a different form of LINQ. I think something like this could work:

```
var jobStatisticsResult = from data in reportData
                    from agentId in data.AgentIds
                    group data by agentId
                    into grp
                    select new { AgentId = grp.Key, Items = grp.ToList() };

var jobStatistics = jobStatisticsResult.ToDictionary(x => x.AgentId, x => x.Items.ToJobsStatistic());
```

Comment: Maybe we can delete  `into grp
                    select new { AgentId = grp.Key, Items = grp.ToList() };` ?

Comment: Yeah could do. Depends on your requirements for the return type